# AWS Aurora MySQL count distinct returns 1 instead of 0

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

When running the following query on AWS aurora I get the result `1`, but I expected 0:

```sql
select count(distinct `t`.`input`)
from `db`.`Transactions` as `t`
  join `db`.`Users` as `user`
    on `user`.`id` = `t`.`userId`
where (
  `t`.`documentId` = 'THIS DOESNT EXIST'
)
```

When omitting the `distinct` keyword, it correctly returns `0`:

```sql
select count(`t`.`input`)
from `db`.`Transactions` as `t`
  join `db`.`Users` as `user`
    on `user`.`id` = `t`.`userId`
where (
  `t`.`documentId` = 'THIS DOESNT EXIST'
)
```

When I run this against a local mysql instance with (almost) the same data, I get `0` with both queries, which is what I would expect.

Is this an AWS Aurora bug? If so, how can I work around this?

Edit: The `t`.`input` is of type `json`. When using a non-json column like `documentId` or `userId` I correctly get the expected `0`.

Screenshot of the problem:

[image]